# Subscribe to WebSocket feed

Tags: c++, websocket

I'm trying to access a WebSocket API using the *cpprestsdk*. The example code I have so far is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cpprest/ws_client.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace web;
using namespace web::websockets::client;

int main() {
  websocket_client client;
  client.connect("wss://api.poloniex.com").wait();

  websocket_outgoing_message out_msg;
  out_msg.set_utf8_message("test");
  client.send(out_msg).wait();

  client.receive().then([](websocket_incoming_message in_msg) {
    return in_msg.extract_string();
  }).then([](string body) {
    cout << body << endl; // test
  }).wait();

  client.close().wait();

  return 0;
}
```

The page ([here](https://poloniex.com/support/api/)) gives the following information:

> In order to use the push API, connect to wss://api.poloniex.com and
>   **subscribe** to the desired feed [...] In order to receive ticker
>   updates, **subscribe** to "ticker".

I can't find out how to subscribe to a channel using this library.

Comment: This is a question about Poloniex, not about websockets themselves. (You need to find out what to send instead of "test")

Comment: AH ok, I thought subscribing is a commonly used word with Websockets.